# How to fix "Element type is invalid " when connecting firebase to React application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

Problems setting up firebase/firestore with react and redux. Been reading through all the docs on http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/getting_started.html and cannot render the application and obtaining the error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Removing ReactReduxFirebaseProvider allows my application to render however it won't be connected to the database. I have checked all my default and named exports however still cannot find the problem.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from './App';
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { firebase} from './config/fbConfig';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// react-redux-firebase config
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true
};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}><App/></ReactReduxFirebaseProvider></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

fbConfig

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const fbConfig = {}; // object containing my Firebase config

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export {
  firebase,
  firestore,
  auth
};
```

I am new to working with firebase and fairly new to react and redux so have probably made a simple mistake however after hours of staring at this error I cannot find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the docs for `react-redux-firebase` http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/ there is no top-level export named `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` so `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` is undefined, hence the error. Doesn't look like `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider` exists in that project at all so maybe it's from a different project?

Comment: Realised my mistake, react-redux-firebase latest version is 2.4.0, however ReactReduxFirebaseProvider is available in the next upcoming version currently in alpha therefore returned undefined as you stated. All I had to do was a reinstall with an @next to get v3.0.0-alpha. A simple glance at the package on the npm website to begin with would have saved me all the hassle!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to open terminal in root directory of project and run:

```
  npm install react-redux-firebase@next
```